# Inserting bootstrap datetime with specific locale format not compatible to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column in my table on MYSQL like this :

```
| TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN | datetime                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Now, in html, I use js from [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I use locale `id` which is Indonesian format. My code is looked like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
     label class="control-label col-md-3">Estimasi</label>
     <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="perkiraan_selesai" class="form-control datetime" type="text">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

$('.datetime').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'id'
});
```

Now the trouble has come. DATETIME on mysql ? I use php like this :
**PHP**

```
$dataMaster = array(
        'ID_KARYAWAN' => $this->input->post('nama'),
        'TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN' => $this->input->post('tanggal_persetujuan'),
        'TANGGAL_TERIMA' => $this->input->post('tanggal_terima'),
        'PERKIRAAN_SELESAI' => $this->input->post('perkiraan_selesai'),
        'TANGGAL_SELESAI' => $this->input->post('tanggal_selesai'),
        'PELAKSANA' => $this->input->post('pelaksana'),
        'KELUHAN' => $this->input->post('keluhan'),
        'CATATAN' => $this->input->post('catatan')
    );


    print_r($this->input->post());
```

The output :

```
Array
(
[id] => 
[nama] => 5
[tanggal_persetujuan] => 23/03/2016 00.00
[tanggal_terima] => 23/03/2016 00.00
[perkiraan_selesai] => 23/03/2016 00.00
[tanggal_selesai] => 23/03/2016 00.00
[pelaksana] => Awan
[tipe] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

[keluhan] => Test
[catatan] => Saja
)
```

Comment: If you get an error, please can you add that into your question. It seems like you're using datatypes wrong - inside your Database: it should be datatype `TIMESTAMP` in your case

Comment: there is no error. I should use datetime coz the time is not live. I just got 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: then are you sure you're inserting the correct data? `var_dump` what you're trying to insert and ensure they are the correct format before inserting them, there should be no issue doing what you're doing or compatibility issues. You're simply inserting dates into a database

Comment: please see on [perkiraan_selesai] => 23/03/2016 00.00, there is no right format on mysql. Is it true ?

Comment: I don't understand your question? You can easily put a datetime into a database no matter what the value is and reference it with a name. I still don't see where the idea of compatibility comes into anything? But yes, you must format it to the datatype inside the database or it will go to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and yes the format is only *American*

Answer (score 0):

You will be having problems as MySQL treats date format as Y-m-d in this case 2016-03-23
I have not used bootstrap dates but have using Jquery ui Datepicker works a treat.
You do need to format the output when retrieving the date back to output to the browser.
When out putting this could be done by breaking the date up into the year month and day and assigning individual variables.
Regards Jase